# List Properties and Convert to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, properties

Is there any way to get a list of properties name from `Properties` and convert it into a `String[]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) implements [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) which has a [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) method which returns a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) with all keys. The `Set` in turn has a [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method which allows you to get the values as a plain array.

So, this should do:

```
String[] keys = properties.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```